# Extreme Confusion on Forks and Execlp

Tags: c++, linux, operating-system, fork, exe

this is my first post.
I have a task to use a fork to create multiple processes and then use execlp to run another program to add 2 numbers.

The problem I am having is we are supposed to use the exit() call in the execlp to return the small integer. This is a bad way to communicate but it's what we are supposed to do for the sake of this program.

Here is my "coordinator" program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/wait.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc,char* argv[])

{
const int size = argc-1;

int sizeArray = 0;

int numofProc =0;

int arrayofNum[size];

int status;

int value;



for(int y=1; y<argc; y++)
{

arrayofNum[y-1] = atoi(argv[y]);

sizeArray++;

}


if(sizeArray % 2 !=0)

{

arrayofNum[sizeArray]  = 0;

sizeArray++;



}



numofProc = sizeArray/2;


//declaration of a process id variable

pid_t pid;


//fork a child process is assigned 

//to the process id

pid=fork();



//code to show that the fork failed

//if the process id is less than 0

if(pid<0)

{

    cout<<"Fork Failed";// error occurred

    exit(-1); //exit

}


//code that runs if the process id equals 0

//(a successful for was assigned

else 

if(pid==0)

{

    //this statement creates a specified child process

     execlp("./worker", "worker", arrayofNum[0], arrayofNum[1]);//child process



}

//code that exits only once a child 

//process has been completed

else

{

waitpid(pid, &status, 0);

cout<<status;


}

//main

}
```

and here is the execlp process

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>


using namespace std;



int main(int argc, char* argv[])

{



int arrayofNum[argc-1];



arrayofNum[0] = atoi(argv[1]);

arrayofNum[1] = atoi(argv[2]);



int sum = arrayofNum[0] + arrayofNum[1];

exit(sum);


}
```

My problem is NO MATTER WHAT I DO, the status is ALWAYS printing a 0, I do not know how to retrieve the sum that is returned from the worker process.

My professor told me ""Only the higher byte of status will have the value returned by the worker. you need to extract it. It can be done by many ways. ""

In a nut shell, my question is, How do I retrieve that "sum" that is being sent from my worker process.

Please, I am so confused and have been up for 2 nights wondering about this

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First up, you need to pass strings to your program, but you say:

```
execlp("./worker", "worker", arrayofNum[0], arrayofNum[1]);
```

And `arrayofNum` is an array of integers. Also, with execlp you also need to pass a `NULL` as the last argument. [The standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/exec.html) says:

> The arguments represented by arg0,... **are pointers to null-terminated
>   character strings**. These strings shall constitute the argument list
>   available to the new process image. **The list is terminated by a null
>   pointer**.

Second, after you call to `waitpid(2)` you need to do:

```
if (WIFEXITED(status))
    code = WEXITSTATUS(status);
```

Comment: Thanks for such a prompt response cnicutar.

I added the necessary corrections but when I cout<< the value = WEXITSTATUS(status);  I get a very large number like

4190812

:\

Comment: @JohnathanMonaco You're probably passing the arguments wrong.

Comment: This is the execlp: execlp("./worker", "worker", arrayofNum[0], arrayofNum[1], NULL);

and the other

wait(&status);
 if (WIFEXITED(status))
 {
     value = WEXITSTATUS(status);
 }

}
 cout<<value;

Comment: @JohnathanMonaco You're not listening :-)) You can't pass `arrayofNum`. You need to pass a `char *`.

Comment: Oh wow, I'm so sorry! Thank you so much! Can I still pass them as individual ones as long as I keep them as characters. Maybe such as execlp("./worker", "worker", arrayofChar[0], arrayofChar[1], NULL);

Or should it be all one array.

I really appreciate your patience with me, this is my first experience with this kind of programming.

Comment: @JohnathanMonaco You need to convert them to `char` arrays. Before trying anything else, try `execlp("./worker", "worker", "10", "20", NULL)`. After you verify that works, find out a way to convert your numbers to C strings, perhaps using `sprintf`.

Comment: cnicutar... I love you so much... thank you.   What happens is the program is tested on the command line like ./coord 1 2 3 4...... so it's already passed in the argv array so it works out perfectly. Thank you soooooo much!